# Change voice in Webchat using BrowserWebSpeech

Tags: botframework

I am trying to enable Text to Speech option in Microsoft Webchat and used the option of createBrowserWebSpeechPonyfillFactory.

How to change voice for this option? i want to use Female voice for 'en-US' but it always plays using Male voice.

Tried the below code, but it didn't help

```
    async function speechServicesPonyfillFactory() {
        const speechServicesPonyfillFactory = await window.WebChat.createBrowserWebSpeechPonyfillFactory();

        return options => {

            const ponyfill = speechServicesPonyfillFactory(options);

            var speechSynthesisUtterance = ponyfill.SpeechSynthesisUtterance;
            var speechSynthesis = ponyfill.speechSynthesis;
            var voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();

            speechSynthesisUtterance.voice = voices.filter(function(voice) { return voice.name == 'Microsoft Zira Desktop - English (United States)'; })[0];
            return {
                SpeechGrammarList: ponyfill.SpeechGrammarList,
                SpeechRecognition: ponyfill.SpeechRecognition,
                speechSynthesis: speechSynthesis,
                SpeechSynthesisUtterance: speechSynthesisUtterance
            }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `selectVoice` method as a prop to Web Chat to select the voice you want to use. Take a look at the code snippet below and the [Select Voice](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/06.g.select-voice) Web Chat sample for more details. Also, here is a list of [voices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support#text-to-speech) Web Chat supports.

```
window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
  {
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
    selectVoice: (voices, activity) =>
      // If the activity is in zh-HK, use a voice with keyword "TracyRUS" (Cantonese).
      // Otherwise, use "JessaNeural" (preferred) or "Jessa".
      activity.locale === 'zh-HK'
        ? voices.find(({ name }) => /TracyRUS/iu.test(name))
        : voices.find(({ name }) => /JessaNeural/iu.test(name)) ||
          voices.find(({ name }) => /Jessa/iu.test(name)),
    webSpeechPonyfillFactory
  },
  document.getElementById('webchat')
);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: So, Selectvoice cannot be used  in BrowserWebSpeech, it can be used only with the CognitiveServicesSpeechServices? because i could see only Server supported voices in the Language support page you shared.

Comment: I think it still works with Browser Speech. I’m just not sure which voices are supported.

Comment: Can you please check this? i couldn't make this work with the names Chrome console shows.

Comment: @Arun, this appears to be an issue with the feature, itself. A bug has been created [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2424). Please feel free to add to the conversation. Doing so will give greater weight to the issue resulting in a possibly quicker solution.